# adding value to a subset of a column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

For the following data frame:

```
index    A    B       C   
0        3    word    7
1        4    type    3
2        8    manic   4
3        9    tour    6
```

I am going to add value to a subset of column A. This is my code:

```
df.A=  df.loc[0:2, 'A' ] + 30
```

But this is there result:

```
  index       A      B       C   
    0        33    word    7
    1        34    type    3
    2        38    manic   4
    3              tour    6
```

makes the value of the fourth row of column A "null". Any suggestion ?

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you're trying to do? You're just trying to add an arbitrary number to a subset of column A?

Comment: @Andrew, yes, I am

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use +=:

```
df.loc[0:2,'A']+=30

df
Out[11]: 
   index   A      B  C
0      0  33   word  7
1      1  34   type  3
2      2  38  manic  4
3      3   9   tour  6
```

Answer (score 3):

What you assign to the new column `A` is a column that is one row shorter than required.  Instead, you should asign a slice to a slice, like I have done below.

Try

```
df.loc[0:2,'A']=  df.loc[0:2, 'A' ] + 30
```